# Unable to install 10.04 after removing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, 10.04, dual-boot

My laptop was dual booting Windows XP and Ubuntu 10.04.

Recently I completely formatted my 250 GB HDD and installed Windows XP in a 5GB partition. Then installed Ubuntu 12.04 in remaining space. But WiFi is found to be slow in 12.04, so I decided to revert back to 10.04.

I removed the Ubuntu partition from Windows and tried to install 10.04. But after 44% it shows an error message that `Copying is not possible....` I thought it may be the problem of installation disk. So again tried to install 10.04 from a USB. But it also shows the same error.

When I restarted, it shows booting error that GRUB was not found. As I am not an expert in Ubuntu, I tried to re-install Windows XP. Then it shows the error `cannot format disk`. So now I am not able to install Ubuntu 10.04 nor Windows XP in my laptop. Then I again tried to install 12.04 and it worked.

How can I revert this 12.04 to 10.04 and install Windows XP?

Comment: Try formatting Hard drive from Ubuntu Live USB , post the specific errors it shows , if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ubuntu live cd/DVD ,go to live session and then system->Administration->Gparted (partition editor). create->partition table and choose MS-DOS type partition table.Note: it will completely clear the HDD. If not format the partitions to NTFS. Then use Windows XP cd and install. Always install windows first and then Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanx for the info.

Comment: Tried this and could able to install windows XP. But still having trouble with ubuntu.  It always shows the error "Copying is not possible...." I tried with many different DVD and USB drives. So this is not the issue with installation media.